# C# coclass - GetTypeInfoCount returns 0

Tags: c#, com, interop, com-interop

I have a C# class that implements an interface defined in a separate external TLB file, imported into my project through interop.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IInterfaceFromSeparateTLB ))]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("4FFBBD0D-6F4B-47D4-B4F9-586F8C108BAD")]
[IDispatchImpl(IDispatchImplType.CompatibleImpl)]
public class MyCoClass : IInterfaceFromSeparateTLB {}
```

When I pass an instance of MyCoClass to a C++ function that takes IDispatch as argument and call IDispatch::GetTypeInfoCount, I always get 0. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling IDispatch::GetTypeInfoCount I forgot to check HRESULT, which was 0x8002802b (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND). I put a copy of .TLB file beside my DLL, then set "Embed Interop Types" option to false, and problem has gone.